# If I need to extend mysql.sql a table inside the field ( ejabberd)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

If I need to extend mysql.sql a table inside the field, such as users table, the default has the following three fields

```
username varchar (250) PRIMARY KEY, 
password text NOT NULL, 
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If I need to add an extra field here, like this

```
username varchar (250) PRIMARY KEY, 
password text NOT NULL, 
sex tinyint NOT NULL, // note add extra fields here. 
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So I ejabberd, I do what the job?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply alter your schema to add the extra needed field. It will not be used by ejabberd, but should not cause any issue.